# Mac not showing external flash drive with turnkey linux installed

Tags: imac, dual-boot, efi

I have been trying to setup a spare iMac (iMac12,2) that I have as a minecraft server, but whenever I try to make the flash drive installer, the mac doesn't recognize the drive in the boot picker (holding down option at boot)... the drive is bootable because an old macbook (MacBook4,1) that I have is able to boot.. I've tried installing rEFInd but when booting into the drive it just displays a black screen, and when using clover bootloader, it just boots into the GRUB bootloader... any ideas?

Comment: The flash drive has a Linux Distro called mineOS on it if that helps

Answer (score 1):

This may be far fetched, but is the USB formatted as GUID partition scheme? The Mac boot program rejects anything other than it with my experiences. And have you checked if the Linux is UEFI compatible? That may be an issue with newer Mac's.

Comment: You can boot a macOS installer from an USB flash drive formatted with an MBR partitioning scheme. I believe this is also true for Windows, if the Mac has had the firmware update included with High Sierra.

Comment: The iMac is on the latest version HS so it has that firmware update

Answer (score 0):

The Linux distro I'm trying to install only supports a legacy bios at the moment, so I'm just going to install Ubuntu Server and use mineOS' python web manager